# Regex to find text (Unicode also) that are not surrounded by p tag in an article and give the text surrounding p tag.How to do it?

Tags: php, regex

I have a article which has content on it . I want to find the unwrapped (unicode also present) full text (which are not surround by any tags) and then surround it by p tag and I also dont want to wrap any other tag like iframe,img tag to be surrounded by p tag. Example code are given below-

```html
<p>line 1 </p>
 বাংলাদেশ আমার দেশ line 2
<p> line 3 </p>
 unwrapped line 4
<p> line 5 </p>
 বাংলাদেশ আমার দেশ line 6
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300">
<iframe src="https://unsplash.it/200/300"></iframe>
 বাংলাদেশ আমার দেশ line 7
```

From the code above shown I want the output like this-

```html
<p>line 1 </p>
বাংলাদেশ আমার দেশ line 2
<p> line 3 </p>
<p>unwrapped line 4</p>
<p> line 5 </p>
<p>বাংলাদেশ আমার দেশ line 6</p>
<img src="https://unsplash.it/200/300">
<iframe src="https://unsplash.it/200/300"></iframe>
<p>বাংলাদেশ আমার দেশ line 7</p>
```

Comment: If the reality is as simple as your examples - [Something like this?](https://regex101.com/r/WTYKhb/1) (I assume the 4th line should also be "wrapped".)

Comment: it works fine . Thanks @ClasG

Comment: But if there any other tag like img tag or iframe tag included on the code it also surround by p tag.I dont want any other tag to be surrounded by p tag. Can u help me with that. Thanks in advance @ClasG

Comment: Can you add to the examples illustrating what you want surrounded, and not. (Also, if I was correct regarding line 4, fix that in the question.)

Comment: I have edited my question and example . Will you please check it. Thanks for the help in advance @ClasG

Comment: If there is a tag in same line after the empty text it also wrap the tag with p tag.But i dont want any other tag to be wrapped. link to regex-https://regex101.com/r/Tt7y2L/4 .Can u help me with that @ClasG.

Comment: That's why I twice said "If the reality is as simple as your examples" ;) It never is. Don't have time right now - let me get back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, "If the reality is as simple as your examples" - then you could simply replace

```
^(?!<).*$
```

with

```
<p>$0</p>
```

It's even simpler than the one given there. It uses a negative look-ahead to make sure the row doesn't start with a `<`, and then matches it all. Replacing that with the match (complete one in group 0 - `$0`) surrounded by the paragraph tag.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WTYKhb/3).

A "bit" more complex:

```
^(?!\s*<[a-z]\w*("[^"\n]*"|'[^'\n]*'|[\w=\s])*>).+$
```

makes sure it's a "complete tag" starting the line.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WTYKhb/6).

**Edit**

Improved second regex. (Explanation why in the links last paragraph.)

**Edit 2**

New requirements ;)

```
^(?!.*<[a-z]\w*("[^"\n]*"|'[^'\n]*'|[\w=\s])*>).+$
```

This makes sure that the line doesn't contain any tags.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/WTYKhb/7)

Comment: It works also in  /^(?!<).*(?!>)/m format better for me. Great help for me Thanks @ClasG

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this if your data is stored on each line:

```
$file = file_get_contents('test.txt');
$arr = preg_split('/(\n|\r)/', $file);
$string = '';

foreach($arr as $k=>$v){

    if (strpos($v, '<p>') === FALSE && mb_detect_encoding($v) === 'UTF-8') { //Per-line: Look for UTF-8 encoding & check if <p> is present

        $arr[$k] = '<p>' . trim($v) . '</p>'; //Trim and replace value in array 
    }

    $string .= $arr[$k]; //Add to new string
}

echo $string;
```

**Output:**

```
<p>line 1 </p>
<p>line 2 বাংলাদেশ আমার দেশ</p>
<p> line 3 </p>
line 4 unwrapped
<p> line 5 </p>
<p>line 6 বাংলাদেশ আমার দেশ</p>
```

Comment: Thanks but it can not be done like this . I hav to use preg_replace for some specific reason.